# Create Ord from existing Ord

Tags: functional-java

If I have a `F<A, B>`, how can I convert an existing `Ord<A>` into an `Ord<B>`?

For example:

```
public class Foo {
    public String name;
}

F<Foo, String> f = new F<Foo, String>() {
    public String f(Foo foo) {
        return foo.name;
    }
};

Ord<String> stringOrd = Ord.stringOrd;

Ord<Foo> fooOrd = ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was in the API for the taking. `comap`:

```
Ord<Foo> fooOrd = Ord.stringOrd.comap(new F<Foo, String>() {
    public String f(Foo foo) {
        return foo.name;
    }
});
```

Comment: for `Ord.intOrd` there is `Ord.intOrd.contramap(f -> f.getInt())`